# How to forcibly enable Dual Graphics/Crossfire support for Kaveri and R7 250?

Tags: gaming, amd-catalyst, crossfire

I recently built one of those newfangled AMD Kaveri systems, but am having a little trouble setting it up for dual graphics/Crossfire. Here is the hardware list:

- Motherboard: ASRock Fatal1ty FM2A88X+ Killer (Updated to BIOS v1.8)
- CPU: A10-7850K
- GPU: GIGABYTE GV-R725O5-2GI Radeon R7 250 2GB 128-Bit GDDR5
- RAM: Mushkin 2x8GB DDR3 2400, Timing: 11-13-13-31, CAS 11 (currently clocked down to act as DDR3 1600 until I can figure out manual timings. Any guides for this would be helpful as well)

After Installing Windows 8.1 and the latest drivers from the web (Catalyst 14.1 Beta), both GPUs show up and work, but the option in the Catalyst Control Center for Dual-Graphics does not appear. I currently have the BIOS set to force the integrated GPU to be enabled with a 2GB RAM reservation, and have tried booting with the monitor attached to the dedicated card and the integrated card individually.

Is there anything else I have to do to get the dual graphics to work?

Comment: reread... afaik you cannot crossfire an integrated card with a dedicated.. though you might be able to pass physics processing to the integrated.

Comment: @steve, They totally can: http://www.pcper.com/reviews/Graphics-Cards/AMD-A8-7600-Kaveri-APU-and-R7-250-Dual-Graphics-Testing-Pacing-Fixed
I had Crossfire working with the first-gen APU, but it sucked. I wanted to try again since the reviews say everything has been fixed with Kaveri.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually figured it out. Turns out you have to have a minimum RAM speed of DDR3 1866. Once I set it to that, Crossfire became available and it works beautifully.